# Question about the proof of Caratheodory's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

In the proof available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)), I do not understand why $\alpha>0$. How can we know for sure that $\lambda_i>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ by definition of the convex hull. If any $\lambda_i = 0$, then the term $\lambda_i{\bf x}_i$ can be removed from the sum, hence the problem is reduced to the case when $\lambda_i > 0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

@Antoine's explanation works for showing $\lambda_i > 0$. Then $\alpha > 0$ follows from the definition of $\alpha$, because the denominator is forced to be above $0$. Remember, from the Wikipedia proof: "not all of the $\mu_j$ are equal to zero". So we're allowed to define such an $\alpha$.